# Add a select box dynamically using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code that is printing out a customers order on an order confirmation screen. It is doing this using `Javascript` to populate a `table` with the information. Ideally I would like to do this in `JQuery`

This is my `HTML`

```
 <!-- Order Confirmation Form -->
    <form action="<?the_permalink()?>" method="post">
    <div id="summary">
    <table id="ordertable">
        <tr><th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Bulk</th>
        <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Comments Box -->
    Comments<br/>
    <textarea name="comments"></textarea><br/>
    <input name="product_list" id="products_field" type="hidden" value="<?= isset($_POST['product_list'])?$_POST['product_list']:'' ?>">
    Next Day Delivery <input type="checkbox" name="next-day-delivery" value="yes" />
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm Order" class="confirmBtn"/>
    </div>
    </form>
```

This is my `JS`

```
//Reference to the order table
var ordertable = document.getElementById("ordertable");

    //Loop through the Array and display in the table
    for(var i = 0; i < productArray.length; i ++){

        //This is the data to display
        console.log("Order Item " + i);
        console.log("StockCode: " + productArray[i].stockCode);
        console.log("Quantity: " + productArray[i].quantity);
        console.log("Bulk: " + productArray[i].bulk);

        var row = ordertable.insertRow(i + 1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell1.innerHTML = productArray[i].stockCode;
        cell2.innerHTML = productArray[i].quantity;
        cell3.innerHTML = productArray[i].bulk;
        cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='button' value='-' class='removeBtn'/><input type='button' value='+' class='addBtn'/><input type='button' value='Delete' class='deleteBtn'/>"
    }
```

This is an image of my page, I can't seem to figure out how I could add a `select` box to the cells below `bulk` (outlined in red). The idea being if `bulk == true` display a `select` box `else` don't show anything. (Some products can be ordered in bulk.)

[image: Screenshot of confirmation page]

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might go about achieving this?

Comment: There's no use of `jQuery` in your code. Please re-tag your question.

Comment: @MelanciaUK maybe it is there to indicates that jQuery solutions are welcome..?

Comment: @TJ that is true, I was told that my code should be in `JQuery`, obviously in the above it is in `JS` but I am open to any suggestions regarding how to implement the solution.

Comment: Also, whoever downvoted the question would you please tell me why? I don't think it's a poorly constructed question and I've made every attempt to make the issue as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe simply something like

```
if(productArray[i].bulk)
 cell3.innerHTML =  "<select><option>1</option>..</select>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
 cell3.innerHTML = (productArray[i].bulk)?'<select><option value="...">...</option></select>':'';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var select = '<select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>';
cell3.innerHTML = productArray[i].bulk?select: '';
```

or just

```
cell3.innerHTML = productArray[i].bulk? '<select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>' : '
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0; i < productArray.length; i ++){

        //This is the data to display
        console.log("Order Item " + i);
        console.log("StockCode: " + productArray[i].stockCode);
        console.log("Quantity: " + productArray[i].quantity);
        console.log("Bulk: " + productArray[i].bulk);

        var row = ordertable.insertRow(i + 1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell1.innerHTML = productArray[i].stockCode;
        cell2.innerHTML = productArray[i].quantity;
        if(productArray[i].bulk) // true means select
        cell3.innerHTML = "<select><option>1</option>..</select>"
        else
        cell3.innerHTML = '';
        ell4.innerHTML = "<input type='button' value='-' class='removeBtn'/><input type='button' value='+' class='addBtn'/><input type='button' value='Delete' class='deleteBtn'/>"
    }
```

Comment: wow..! totally different from my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24203765/2333214). even the number of dots!